# What does CreateBus() do [NServicebus]?

Tags: nservicebus

I have this as my initialization code for NServiceBus:

```
        Configure.Serialization.Json();
        Configure.Transactions.Disable(); // No idea why this is set...
        Configure.Features.Disable<AutoSubscribe>(); // This endpoint only sends commands, it never receives events, so it does not need to subscribe to anything.

        Configure
            .With(AllAssemblies.Except("evointernal.dll"))
            .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
            .ForMvc()
            .UseTransport<Msmq>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
            .FileShareDataBus("c:\\NServiceBus_DataBus")
            .CreateBus();

        Configure
            .Instance
            .Configurer
            .ConfigureComponent<OutgoingMessageMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
```

And it's pretty slow - several seconds tax I have to pay every time I recompile in development.  It looks like the lion's share of the time is taken by the CreateBus() call and it raises a few related questions:

1. What does `CreateBus()` do?
2. Why is it so slow?
3. If I don't want to run it in development, what is the alternative way to do whatever it does?

Unfortunately the [NSB docs](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/using-nservicebus-with-asp.net-mvc) are not much help on this.

Comment: Your question is basically "What does NServiceBus do?"

Comment: Not at all.  My question is "why is NSB's init code so slow, and is there a way to run it manually when needed".

Comment: Ok.  It's slow because it is initializing a complex piece of infrastructure: an Enterprise Service Bus.  What it does is not trivial, and thus requires some time to start up.  You can comment it out while developing, or use configuration to decide whether to initialize it or not when running in development mode.  However, without knowing what your system is using NSB for, it's impossible to say whether or not that is a good idea.

Comment: Yeeeeah, I know what NSB does.  What I don't know is what CreateBus() does or why it's necessary - is it checking for and creating the queues if necessary?  Because I'd like to skip that step while developing and run it manually, e.g. via PowerShell cmdlets only when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure is a fluent API where define how to configure your bus. CreateBus() is what actually kicks it off. Look at [this code](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/def31db15977a6017737f134c15d1698edff97e0/src/NServiceBus.Core/Unicast/UnicastBus.cs#L647) and it might also explain why it takes time.